# protobuf-net : list with null elements

Tags: list, serialization, null, deserialization, protobuf-net

```
public MyType {

  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public int Index;

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public string Name;

  public MyType() {
  }

  public MyType(int index, string name) {
    Index = index;
    Name = name;
  }
}

var element0 = new MyType(0,"element index 0");
var element1 = null;
var element2 = new MyType(2,"element index 2");
var list = new List<MyType> {element0, element1, element2}
```

Since element index 1 is null , `protobuf-net` serializer will omit that element from the serialized bytes.

On the other side of the wire, something very interesting happens :

`protobuf-net` deserializer reads the bytes, learns that 3 elements are expected, but only finds bytes for elements index 0 and 2.  So it creates element index 1 as an empty instance of `MyType`.

So the deserialized list is equivalent to :

```
var element0 = new MyType(0,"element index 0");   
var element1 = new MyType(0,null); 
var element2 = new MyType(2,"element index 2");
var list = new List<MyType> {element0, element1, element2}
```

But this is not what is expected. Null is not the same thing as an empty object, and the presence of an element with duplicate Index=0 and Name=null can have serious adverse consequences for the processing code - which rightfully should not be aware of nor concerned with serdes details.

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no, there's no workaround for this and it is not a supported scenario in protobuf-net. The underlying protocol buffers format (which protobuf-net implements) **has no concept of null**; there is no way for me to represent a null instance inside the regular format. A list of classes is simply a repeated chunk of length-prefixed nodes, so (in a dense binary format, not text):

```
[field 1, length-prefixed] [length prefix] [payload for element index 0]
[field 1, length-prefixed] [length prefix] [payload for element index 1]
[field 1, length-prefixed] [length prefix] [payload for element index 2]
... etc
```

The only two options I have for nulls in a list are:

- ignore them
- treat them as zero-length

Protobuf-net currently uses the second approach, but: a zero-length class is essentially `new MyType()`; zero-length is perfectly valid and well-defined in protocol buffers.

Unlike some other formats, there isn't really anywhere I can add extra metadata to say "I'm a null" (`@xsi:nil` in xml, for example).

It *might* be possible for me to hack this into the "preserve references" code, but I've checked, and support for nulls isn't there currently - I accept that this is a bit of an oversight, but I would also emphasize that the "preserve references" code **is not standard protobuf**, and any other libraries (java, golang, etc) may have difficulty consuming that configuration; I would *only* advocate that if you know you're only talking protobuf-net to protobuf-net. And of course, the null support doesn't currently exist, and would need hacking in :)

Comment: Thanks Mark.  In another post of yours I found this workaround :   `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (YourType)][1].SupportNull = true;`  Is this still supported ?  If so, do you advise using it ? What are pros/cons ?

Comment: @BaltoStar well damn, I'd forgotten all about that! Feel free to try it - let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks Mark. Any plans to add this feature as a proxy-class annotation ?

Comment: In a test setup context, when I configure null support for multiple types `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (MyType)][1].SupportNull = true;` `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (MyEmbeddedType)][2].SupportNull = true;` `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (MySubType)][3].SupportNull = true;` I'm getting sporadic null ref errors. Bizarrely, it seems to depend on the values and ordering of the proto-indexes chosen.

Comment: The RuntimeTypeModel.Default... method works for me. It would be nice to be available in the protomember attribute.